# Get a ListView ItemTemplate index on a CommandArgument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to get a `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate` index on a `CommandArgument` from an `ImageButton` inside the `ItemTemplate`?

Something like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("INDEX_OF_ITEM").ToString() %>'
```

I have a `ListView` with an `ImageButton` inside the `ItemTemplate` and I need to get that Item's index on code behind.

This is what I have now on code behind:

```
Dim b As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)
Dim item As ListViewDataItem = TryCast(b.Parent, ListViewDataItem)
Dim i As Integer = item.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(item)
i = i - 1
Response.Write(i)
```

This code only gets the index of the first row of the `ListView`. I have the `GroupItemCount` set to '3' so i only get 1, 2 and 3 as index (the first row).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have just solved it with this:

```
CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>'
```